# Add custom status to nebular

Tags: angular, nebular

I am currently creating a web app using Angular 13 & Nebular 9.0.0 and i'm figured out if it's possible to add custom status. By default, nebular as multiple status:

Primary, Control, Basic, Danger, Warning, Success, Info but what if a wanna add a Secondary status using my secondary color ?

if someone have the answer it will be really useful for me.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit an theme, which holds color variables and add a new variable "Secondary". There are quite a few places you'd need to change.

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/eva-design-system-intro#eva-design-system

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components